# Is it more performant to create methods in my model or in a view helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I am creating a family tree and I will create methods that calculate various relationships on-the-fly (e.g. "siblings", "spouses", etc.).

A few years ago the whole "fat model, skinny controller" paradigm took hold of the Rails community, so that has been my default position - just drop them in the `User` model. But with Rails 4 pushing concerns and helpers so much, I am now wondering which is the best option.

Should I just drop them in my `User` model, or put them in my `DashboardHelper` (given that they will be used in the `Dashboard#Index`), this is from a performance perspective.

I guess the issue is that ALL methods may not be called on EVERY `Dashboard` view, but if I put them in the `DashboardHelper` are all methods instantiated on every `Dashboard#Action`?

Which is better from a performance perspective and why?

Comment: Are you sure the difference would even be measurable?

Comment: helpers are view helpers, you use them for view specific stuff, is whatever you're doing just a view thing ( like for example creating options html for a select tag ) or is it a query and calculations and stuff, if so then i'd say it should be in the model

Comment: @icktoofay It may be, because of the number of calculations per view load.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady It is calculations and stuff. That's what I was thinking...but just wanted clarification.

Comment: also make sure to eager load, and not fall into a n+1 queries

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady can I eager load from within the model? I definitely was aware of the N+1 issue though, for sure.

Comment: ofcourse you can, User.includes(:something_else).where(whatever), just wrap it in a function to make it maintainable

Comment: Yeh...most definitely will. By function I am sure you meant method....and I got you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the overall loading time is decreased when data is sent to the view.

Create data-fetching and querying methods in the model (preferable) or the controller and pass the data **TO** the view.

The view expects data to be delivered to it. Otherwise when it has to fetch data itself (like queries being made from the view or helper methods that query the database or arrange some huge hash/array a certain way), then the view rendering speed naturally suffers.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a more detailed Rails explanation (e.g. based on the middleware that manages view helpers vs AR or something of the sort).

Comment: @marcamillion you should explain your problem more your self to help us give you better answers, like what's the relations and what are u calculating